# Laravel 5.4 - route model binding condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have implemented route model binding as follows:

Route:

```
Route::get('property/{property}', 'PropertyController@view');
```

Controller:

```
public function view(Property $property)
{
    $data = compact([
        'property'
    ]);

    return view('property.view', $data);
}
```

This works great. However I want to add a condition to the Property model to check that `active = 1`. How and where do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? You're basically asking how use an if-statement...

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the model, instead of the controller?

Comment: The documentation mentions explicit binding; will this work for you? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#explicit-binding

Comment: what would you like to do after checking 'active' is equal to 1 or not? if active is not equal to 1, do you want to redirect the page to some other page or what?

Comment: @RubanrajRavichandranit will just throw a 404 exception. It does this by default already, for example if the property ID does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can register an explicit binding. Add the code below to `RouteServiceProvider`. This will be applied to the model binding when the segment is `property`.

```
Route::bind('property', function ($id) {
    return \App\Property::where('id', $id)
        ->where('active', 1)
        ->firstOrFail();
});
```

If you need this condition to be applied globally for every result then you can add a global scope instead. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#global-scopes